# order my pair RDD by key

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

i created my pair RDD and i need it to be sorted :

```
JavaPairRDD< String, String> pairsP= csvFileP.mapToPair(new keyData()).sortByKey(true).cache();
```

My question is : i wanted to use an int key in my pairRdds  `javapairRdd<int,string>`
 But it occured an error , so i tried with  `javapairRdd<Integer,string>` and there i got no errors but when i used the function `sortByKey()` i found that it treats keys as strings not as integers.
 For eg i have keys such: (1,...),(3,..),2(,...),(12,..),(22,..)
 The result which i look for after sorting is: (1,..),(2,..),(3,...),(12,..),(22,..)
 But i found this: (1,..),(12,..),(2,..),(22,..),(3,...)
 So is there any possibility to make my keys to be an int?

if not how can i sort my rdd as i wish?
finally, is it possible to stop sweeping my RDD by verifying a condition on keys ?

Comment: what kind of error did you get putting the int as key?

Comment: the error is : syntax error, insert 'Dimensions' to complete TypeArgument